Slider not work from time to time, after moving the widget in edit mode it works again (without changing code)
I created some custom slider for my client and sometimes - i don't know why - all the sliders only work in edit mode but not at the frontend.
When i move the widgets up or down and click save, the slider works again.
I load my widgets via elementor/frontend/init. Do i miss something?
$(window).on('elementor/frontend/init', function () {
        elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction(
            'frontend/element_ready/wis-testimonial-slider.default',
            WisSliderHandler
        )

        elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction(
            'frontend/element_ready/wis-benefits-slider.default',
            WisSliderHandler
        )

        elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction(
            'frontend/element_ready/wis-news-slider.default',
            WisSliderHandler
        )

        elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction(
            'frontend/element_ready/wis-portfolio-slider.default',
            WisSliderHandler
        )

        // elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction(
        //  'frontend/element_ready/wis-widget-history-slider.default',
        //  WisSliderHandler
        // )
    })


let WisSliderHandler = function ($scope, $) {
    console.log(window.wisDevMode ? 'WisSwiperHandler loaded' : '')
    let $swiper = $scope.find('.wis-swiper')

    if (!$swiper.length) {
        return
    }

    let $options = $swiper.data('options')

    let swiper = new Swiper(`.${$options.slider_name}`, {
        modules: [Navigation], // Pagination
        autoHeight: true,
        setWrapperSize: true,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        parallax: true,
        loop: $options.loop,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
            type: 'bullets',
        },

        // slidesPerView: 1,
        // spaceBetween: 20,
        breakpoints: {
            640: {
                slidesPerView: $options.items_count_mobile, // 1.2,
                spaceBetween: $options.space_between_mobile, // 1.2,
            },
            990: {
                slidesPerView: $options.items_count_tablet, // 3.2,
                spaceBetween: $options.space_between_tablet, // 1.2,
            },
            1024: {
                slidesPerView: $options.items_count, // 4.2,
                spaceBetween: $options.space_between, // 1.2,
            },
        },

        navigation: {
            nextEl: `.${$options.slider_name}-next`,
            prevEl: `.${$options.slider_name}-prev`,
        },
    })

